# Euler class of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, connections, characteristic-classes

While computing the Euler class of the manifold, can we use connections other than the Levi-Civita connection ? What is the restriction on the connection that can be used to compute the Euler class ?

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific by mentioning, in your question, the exact formula you are hoping to generalize.

Comment: @LeeMosher Euler characteristics is defined for manifolds of even dimensions. So I am asking for all of them.

Comment: In fact, Euler characteristic is defined for all compact manifolds of all dimensions, even for all compact CW complexes. However, your question seems to presuppose some specific formula for the Euler characteristic, a formula which is expressed in terms of the Levi-Civita connection. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I thought you wanted a more general *formula*.

Comment: @LeeMosher Wait, maybe I am confusing Euler class with Euler characteristic. Are they different ?

Comment: Yes. They are defferent Euler class is a cohomology class and characteristic is an integer.

Comment: @LeeMosher I am sorry I confused Euler Characteristic with Euler class. I am very sorry.

Comment: I think you have $\int_M\text{Pf}\big(\frac{1}{2\pi}\Omega\big)=\chi(M)$ for $2m$ dimension manifold with metric connection. And you are looking for more general. Well odd dimensional compact manifold has zero Euler characteristic.

Comment: @Sumanta You mean the connection need not be torsionless ?

Comment: Sorry, I have to write more clearly. Add the following also. $M$ is compact oriented Riemannian. Consider an metric connection on tangent bundle. Where $\Omega$ is the curvature form of positively oriented orthonormal frame.

Comment: Also, general Gauss-Bonnet says, $\int_Me(TM)=\chi(M)$, again even dimension.

Comment: @Sumanta No. I understand. I just wish to know whether the connection can have torsion when computing the Euler Class.

Comment: If you want to know how to define Euler characteristic in Algebraic Topology, I can undelete my answer. I kept it aside from downvoter.

Comment: @Sumanta No. I think I got my answer. I just wanted to confirm whether a connection with torsion maybe used to compute the Euler class.